# Libgdx viewport distortion issue

Tags: java, view, libgdx

I swear I can never get anything with the Stage class to work as I want it to...
anyways, I've been experimenting with viewports, and it worked fine with the gamescreen where I'm using a spritebatch. The problems occurred with the main menu and game over screens that uses the Stage class.

When I resize while the gamescreen is open and then returns to the main menu or game over screen, the widgets are distorted. If I then go back to the gamescreen again it's fine.

This is the code that has worked best so far. Still not working correctly though...

```
public class MyGame extends Game {

public OrthographicCamera camera;
public Viewport viewport;
public SpriteBatch batch;

public static final int WIDTH = 960;
public static final int HEIGHT = 540;

public static MainMenu mainmenu;

@Override
public void create() {

    mainmenu = new MainMenu(this);

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(true, 1920, 1080);
    viewport = new FitViewport(1920, 1080, camera);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    setScreen(mainmenu);
}
```

resize method in every class:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    game.viewport.update(width, height);
}
```

So, I'm using one FitViewport across every class. I've also tried to use a viewport for each class, but the result only got worse...

One more thing.

When I resize the window, the viewport does not update while I'm resizing. Instead it creates a black bar around it till I release. I don't think it's supposed to do that. Every tutorial I've watched were they've resized a window have had the screen update while they're resizing.

Any ideas on why it does that?